# Update statement produces error when empty value given

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

New and struggling with PDO/SQL and have drafted a sql update statement that produces a fatal error. I am looking for help in understanding and resolving the error. I have checked my syntax and it appears to be correct, but I am new, so even the obvious might be beyond me at times.

This is the statement which produces the fatal error *SQLSTATE[42000]*

```
$sql  = "UPDATE  `frm_THREAD`
SET
`charID`   =  :charID,
`modID`    =  :modID,
`userID`   =  :userID,
`catID`    =  :catID,
`groupID`  =  :groupID,
`eventID`  =  :eventID,
`eventID`  =  :eventID,
`factionID =  :factionID
WHERE `threadID` = :threadID; ";
```

The sql generated the following fatal error:
*Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'storyID`= ?,`teamID`= ? WHERE`threadID` = ?' at line 11*

If I read the error correctly, this is line #11: *`factionID = :factionID,*

In an attempt to resolve this error, I have read my manual and my snytax appears correct to me. I have googled away for a few hours and read a great many posts regarding this issue on StackOverflow. Everything I look at suggests I have written the sql correctly, but the error remains So I am clearly not seeing something or not understanding something as my test fails.

I have done a var dump of all values, and they are as follows. The values that have a zero reading (which I believe are actually empty ''/have no value given) is where the sql errors out.

```
$threadID   = 6; # var_dump result
$charID     = 38;# ''
$modID      = 3; # ''
$userID     = 3; # ''
$catID      = 0; # ''
$groupID    = 0; # ''
$eventID    = 0; # ''
$factionID  = 0; # ''
$storyID    = 0; # ''
$teamID     = 0; # var_dump result
```

Image of my database:
[image]

I have stepped through the my sql, checking all the *back ticks*, and *commas*, and *equal signs* and that the *entities* are correctly names. Everything appears to be fine, but I get the above error and am hoping someone can help find my mistake. Thanks in advance for any and all help - I am new, but I am trying and I have researched this a bit before asking for help.

Thank you.

Comment: Typo: `\`factionID =` is missing the second backtick, should be `\`factionID\` =`. P.S. The error message doesn't match the query you've shown...there is no storyID or teamID in your query (although you seem to be setting eventID twice which is weird...did you perhaps re-type your query into Stackoverflow instead of pasting it? Never do that, it just causes extra issues.

Comment: P.P.S. Empty variables would not create a syntax error, because they are not part of the query - they're only added in to replace the placeholders _after_ the basic syntax has been checked (which is why parameterised queries prevent SQL injection and other types of syntax error).

Comment: @ADyson I had some challenges getting my question into the editor which had me pasting each line of the sql in. I don't like the 'helper' as it's not very helpful, all i can figure is that the text editor i used to write my question isn't compatible with Stack?  I am looking at your suggestions now - thank you.

Comment: `all i can figure is that the text editor i used to write my question isn't compatible with Stack`...possibly, especially if you used tabs instead of spaces to indent your code. But https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting explains all about how to use the Stackoverflow editor and get your question looking good.

Comment: I believe you lead me to a solution, and your notes on the placeholders after the basic syntax regarding parameterized queries preventing SQL injects was illuminating to me as it was very concise. I now have a new error and that is for another question. Thank you. @ADyson